# category_description() shows raw html after version 3.x?

Tags: categories

Just looking for some history on the output of category_description()

I have categories whose "description" fields are formatted with rich text and I'm trying to understand the differences in WP version with respect to the output of this method so that I can do a version check if necessary to implement desired output.

For example, before 3.0.1, it appears that category_description() returned the output stripped of any html markup. However, with the current 3.3.1 release, the output appears to be raw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually HTML is stripped on input, using `wp_filter_kses` function hooked into `pre_term_description` filter. So if this hook isn't removed HTML would be stripped.

Comment: OK, I'm already calling that filter, so no problems. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You're very welcome.